# Vuetify v-select not showing items after full refresh

Tags: vuex, vuetify.js

I have a dialog with a v-select that doesn't show values in the drop down after a full page load. It does work after a hot module reload triggered by modifying the component file.

Using vuetify:

```
"vuetify": "^1.5.17",
```

Component contains:
template code:

```
  <v-select
      :items="routes"
      label="Routes"
      multiple
      chips
      persistent-hint
      hint="Send to which routes"
      v-model="message.routes"
  ></v-select>
```

routes is a computed property:

```
routes: {
  get() {
    return this.$store.state.routes
  }
}
```

The data gets downloaded in the created event:

```
  created() {
    this.downloadRoutes()
  }
```

This maps to a store method that does an AJAX call that commits the returned list:

```
downloadRoutes({ commit, state }) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    commit('SET_LOADING', true)
    api.get('/route').then(response => {
      var routes = response.data.routes

      commit('SET_ROUTES', routes)
      commit('SET_LOADING', false)
      resolve()
    })
      .catch(function(error) {
        commit('SET_LOADING', false)
        reject()
      })
  })
},
```

AJAX response is just an array of routes:

```
{"routes":["Route1","Route2","RouteXX"]}
```

This I have shown by doing a console.log of the response and the state in the computed routes property.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your problem lies somewhere inside the vue instance lifecycle, i.e. you might call this.downloadRoutes() inside the wrong hook. Do your problem still occure if you try with a hardcoded array of Routes?

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem.

My store is initialised via an initialState function.

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: initialState,
  getters: {
  ......
```

The initial state function declares all the top level collections used in state.

```
function initialState() {
  return {
    fullName: localStorage.fullName,
    routes: [] // Was missing
}
```

Adding routes in that initial state solves the problem.

I think it's because watchers on state are not added when new attributes are added to state.

When I do a full page refresh the routes gets added to state after the select is initialized and so it is not watching for changes. During hot module reload the routes is already in the state and is so picked up by the select.